# Getting details of likes and comments of a particular post id in ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I am doing a native ios application in which i am making a post on facebook programmatically depending on the user inputs. I could able to post and could also able to get the post id. Now i want to get the details of the likes, comments and shares that the post have got for the future manipulations. I am using me/feed method to post in facebook. I am in this issue for 3days. Any little help will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get like count you can use following code may be its help you.
Just do a simple url request to the Graph API:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[FULL URL]

Example:
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.stackoverflow.com

Edit: (an example with "LIKES")
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

Example :  http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
```

Or Just call a new request with the FB object:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"PHOTO_ID/likes"];

Replace PHOTO_ID with the Facebook ID of the photo you're interested in. This call will return an array with all like information for that photo.

In the -facebook requestDidLoad: method, just get the count of that array to return the number of likes.

NSInteger likeCount = [result count];
```

Comment: Hi. Now i could get the count of the result but i want to know all the details about the likes. Will that be present in the result. If present how to access that. I tried to access like [result objectForKey:@"data"] but it didnt work. u have any idea. Thank you in Advance.